# Override dimple tooltip text only

Tags: dimple.js

How do I override the label / value of a tooltip while maintaining all other formatting?

I have tried incorporating the following examples and have been able to override the text, but the formatting always follows the example. I end up with either the sketchy arrow which doesn't fit in my svg or the text is in top right corner.

1. http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_custom_styling
2. http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_bars_sketchy
3. http://annapawlicka.com/pretty-charts-with-dimple-js/

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I eventually got around to using.

```
series.getTooltipText = function (e) {
    var capitalized_metric = metric.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + metric.substring(1) + "s";
    return [
        "Date: " + moment(e.x).format("MM/DD/YYYY"),
        capitalized_metric + ": " + e.y
    ];
};
```